# get duplicate count in sheet2 in this vba

Tags: excel, vba

i have applied this vba code to copy unique data to sheet2 from sheet1 when i do data entry in sheet1 & this vba is perfectly working for me & here i want how to add get count of duplicates in column E of each entry data in sheet2 of duplicates in sheet1

i doing data entry in column A to column D sheet1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
Sheet1.Range("A2:D" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy Sheet2.Range("A2:D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Sheet2.Range("A2", Sheet2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).RemoveDuplicates 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unique List in a Worksheet Change

- It is triggered when cells in the range `A2:D1048576` (former `A2:D65536`) are 'modified' (even if you click into it and press enter, not changing the value).
- It uses a dictionary whose keys hold the unique values and whose items hold their count.
- It will write the values from the `A:D` range to an array which will be modified appropriately (results written to the top, array increased by a column, count written to the extra column), and used to write the unique values to the destination. The `dr` variable holds the number of rows of the result.
- It will copy only values and clear the range below the results.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Const sCols As String = "A:D"
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    Const sDupeColumn As Long = 1

    Const dfCellAddress As String = "A2"

    Dim sfrrg As Range: Set sfrrg = Me.Rows(sfRow).Columns(sCols)
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = sfrrg.Resize(Me.Rows.Count - sfrrg.Row + 1)

    If Intersect(scrg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no intersection

    Dim slRow As Long
    slRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, sDupeColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    If slRow < sfRow Then Exit Sub ' no data

    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = slRow - sfRow + 1
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sfrrg.Resize(srCount)
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count

    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value

    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    Dim sKey As Variant
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim c As Long

    For sr = 1 To UBound(Data)
        sKey = Data(sr, sDupeColumn)
        If Not IsError(sKey) Then
            If Not IsEmpty(sKey) Then
                If dict.Exists(sKey) Then
                    dict(sKey) = dict(sKey) + 1
                Else
                    dr = dr + 1
                    dict(sKey) = 1
                    For c = 1 To scCount
                        Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
                    Next c
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sr

    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = scCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve Data(1 To srCount, 1 To dcCount)
    dr = 0

    For Each sKey In dict.Keys
        dr = dr + 1
        Data(dr, dcCount) = dict(sKey)
    Next sKey

    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = Sheet2.Range(dfCellAddress)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(dr, dcCount)

    Application.EnableEvents = False ' before writing

    ' Copy
    'srg.Copy dfCell ' if you need the formatting
    drg.Value = Data
    
    ' Clear below.
    Dim dcrg As Range
    Set dcrg = drg.Resize(Sheet2.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr)
    dcrg.Clear

SafeExit:
    If Application.EnableEvents = False Then
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' after writing
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error'" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```

Comment: I've corrected the code. You need to disable events only before writing to the worksheet (so the event doesn't get re-triggered (often severely slowing down the operation or even crashing Excel due to an endless loop) and enable them after the writing. See the new position of `Application.EnableEvents = False`.

Answer (score 0):

i use matrix formula
[image: count duplicates]

you type

```
=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$11=B1;1;0))
```

and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to turn our formula to matrix formula
then you can copy to other cells

**answering your comment**

you can get duplicates with matrix formulate but with many lines like 7000
can take more time for your pc calculate the worksheet around 20seconds

look the image, i put numbers in "A2:B16" and make first one cell with matrix formulate(B2) type:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$16; MATCH(0; COUNTIF(B$1:$B1; $A$2:$A$16); 0));"")
```

and before exit press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to turn our formula to matrix formula
then you can copy to other cells

[image: Unique itens]

and to count duplicates just type

```
=CONTIF($A$2:$A$16;B2)
```

em press ENTER ,after copy and paste above

[image: count duplicates]

Comment: i need get duplicate count in sheet2  from sheet1 duplicates automatically based on data entry on sheet1

Comment: becareful if you use VBA "Worksheet_Change" the UNDO gonna be disable